# The best protein intake to build muscles

Tags: workout

Protein is present in a lot of foods: Fruits, vegetables and plenty of other sources. First of all: Is it all the same? Or are there different types of protein? Second: Chicken for example contains protein (it belongs to category of foods) and banana contains protein (it belongs to fruits category), quaker contains protein (category unknown for me) and some vegetables contain protein too, also eggs. 

Which food is better for our body to create muscles and why or is same?

Third question: Even in category of foods the protein differs, too. Chicken, red meat and foods like beans have different values for human body-muscles, as far as I've heard. Which option is better for foods?

Which of those types of protein is more helpful to build muscle? (Avoid healthy way, my "exams" was very good. I look care what I eat but I may increase some of those for better results that's why I am asking-of course I am not talking about anabolic or steroids. I hope you understand me about this "healthy" foods which are better.)

Comment: *"it belongs to category of foods"* - to my knowledge bananas are food, too. I've tried to clean up your question a bit, but parts of it is still hard to understand.

Comment: I'm actually looking for a more comprehensive list myself. You know, one that includes like elk, buffalo, ostrich eggs, etc. Uncommon stuff.

Comment: See the answers about basic nutrition [here](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/13501/what-are-some-reliable-and-free-basic-online-nutrition-courses) too.

Comment: Read this recently and thought back to this question: http://www.montanaelk.com/nutrition.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out NutritionExpress' protein rankings and relevant info [here](https://www.nutritionexpress.com/article+index/authors/editor/showarticle.aspx?articleid=743):

[image]

Also, be aware of complementary protein paring. See [here](http://health.bastyr.edu/news/health-tips/2011/09/what-are-complementary-proteins-and-how-do-we-get-them) for starters.

And you should be acquainted with the notion of proper/optimal absorption of nutrients too. See [here](http://www.onegreenplanet.org/natural-health/important-nutrients-you-need-for-healthy-digestion/) for that. It's not mentioned in the linked article, but a good way to absorb magnesium is [through the skin](http://www.ancient-minerals.com/transdermal-magnesium/how-topical/), so rub it all over your body<sup>*</sup> before you take a bath/shower or something.

I put chlorophyll in my tea too, which [I've come to believe](http://www.academicfoodjournal.com/archive/2011/issue2/26-32.pdf) helps in long term absorption of protein via its ability to clean the intestines:

[image]

I know it's not what the question asked, but I'd like to also add that using the [MyPlate](https://www.choosemyplate.gov) resource as a *guide* (as opposed to strict adherence) is a good practice and try to be as primitively inspired while shopping/hunting/foraging as feasibly possible, *i.e.*, in the sense of (a mix between) Michael Pollan's ethos in [The Omnivore's Dilemma](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0143038583):

**The Omnivore's Dilemma SPOILER ALERT:**

> The final section finds Pollan attempting to prepare a meal using only ingredients he has hunted, gathered, or grown himself. He recruits assistance from local foodies, who teach him to hunt feral pigs, gather wild mushrooms, and search for abalone. He also makes a salad of greens from his own garden, bakes sourdough bread using wild yeast, and prepares a dessert from cherries picked in his neighborhood. Pollan concludes that the fast food meal and the hunter-gatherer meal are "equally unreal and equally unsustainable". He believes that if we were once again aware of the source of our food – what it was, where it came from, how it traveled to reach us, and its true cost – we would see that we "eat by the grace of nature, not industry".

...and a "[Paleo Diet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paleolithic_diet)":

[image]

But, like I said, use these as a guide as opposed to a strict singular dietary adherence. In practice it's a subtle balance of them all. If you're a vegan it's trickier: In my own experience as a vegan---in the past, but not anymore---for six years it's how well you can pair proteins, the time you can spend preparing this, and the amount of plant-based food you can consume in a day, but it is possible. Check out an example of [Kendrick Farris](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sHeyp2UwLQE&t=1m43s)'s approach, and there are a lot of other examples. But I quit this way of eating because of prep time (see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ylG8b8ivy7M&t=6m50s) for an idea), and it's my understanding (I could be wrong) that our dentition---canine teeth---is reflective of our nature/evolution to eat meat that contains the concentrated nutrients formed from the animal's efforts from consuming mostly plant-based foods. Personally, I try to eat two/three wholly vegan meals a week.

If you're body building, you've got to remain kinda consistent, so I'd recommend a "meal prep" schedule of some kind:

[image]

Working out in the morning increases your metabolism throughout the day, which I find compliments a scheduled meal plan, but I also dislike sameness, so I do that every other day (3-to-4 prep'd meals a week) with random snacks/meals and eating out on off days<sup>**</sup>.

---

<sub>* If you like Conan O'Brien, you'll like [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NwsoBtqoB8A&t=1m9s) that touches on magnesium absorption.</sub>

<sub>** I hope this hasn't come off as a humblebrag-type rant. I can assure you my heart is in the right place.</sub>

Comment: I'd stay away from soy.

Comment: Although, I will admit, some of the chlorophyll properties do slightly sound like something you'd read off the back of a bottle of snake oil sold out of the back of a wagon in the 1850s.

Comment: Complementary proteins are only needed in diets that include no animal products. Pretty much all animal proteins are complete.

Comment: @JohnP, yes, but one should not eat only animal products, so when you must eat non-animal products containing protein, then this ought to be done complementarily.

Comment: Depends on the length of time you don't eat animal products. Not sayong it isn't good info, but a few days isn't really enough to worry about.

Comment: Yeah? How's that?

Comment: Typically a food that is considered incomplete is because it has one ore more "limiting" amounts of the 9 essential amino acids. However, even at that, almost all contain at least trace amounts of the limiter (i.e. even incomplete proteins have some of everything). Unless you completely fast, a few days of eating completely plant based won't be enough to impact your workouts significantly, even if you don't fully eat complementary proteins. (Esp if you eat a variety of foods).

Answer (score -1):

Chicken, turkey, beef, fish, eggs, milk, cheese, yogurt.

Comment: Why? Why are these protein sources better than lentils, chickpeas, soy, beans, etc?